# Compositor to VSE caching workflow

Tags: video-sequence-editor, compositing-nodes, cache

Does anyone can confirm that VSE caching workflow is working in Blender 2.79 as is instructed in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=icDGunOwK-k

I`m not sure if I missed something?

[image]

Comment: Yeah I've had trouble getting it to work. Not sue its cacheing anymore. Check that your Timeline window has ALL frames checked not AV sync or Drop Frame.

Comment: AV sync or Drop Frame unchecked. It seems that it's not working anymore. I've also tested different timeline playback combinations .